# Static headset USB connection

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio

%Windows 7, X99-Deluxe, Corsair H1500

I replaced a headset who had static issues (along with bad cables that broke for a 2nd time) and replaced it with a H1500 corsair headset.
The sound was REALLY LOUD, I had the volume setting at 2 of 100 and still my ears hurt. Used this [How can I lower the volume of my USB headphones?](https://superuser.com/questions/170699/how-can-i-lower-the-volume-of-my-usb-headphones) fix to normalise the sound. The problem now is that I:

1) Have constant static just barley audible
2) After any sound (skype/youtube/music) there is an increase in static while playing and that static stays with for 1 second then it drops back again.

Please help save my hearing.